# UI5: how to remove icons from sap.m.IconTabFilter?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sapui5

I am trying to make my app being responsive. For small displays, I would like to remove the `IconTabFilter` icons using CSS. Until now, I am checking the user agent in JS and add the icons manually to the `IconTab` (or omit them).

Is there a way to hide the icons in the icon tab using CSS? I'm using media queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `text` property of `IconTabFilter`, and leave the `icon` property empty. Then you will have the text-only IconTab.

See the [example.](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBarNoIcons)

Comment: Allen, I want to remove these icons by using css!

Comment: Since you can use existing APIs, why are you using CSS?

Comment: Because I am using media queries

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make my app being responsive. For small displays, I would like to remove the `IconTabFilter` icons using CSS.

You might not need any custom CSS rules for that. Try leveraging the [`sap/ui/Device`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.Device) module instead:

1. Set a device model to the app:

   ```js
   sap.ui.define([
     "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
     "sap/ui/Device",
     "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
     // ...
   ], function(UIComponent, Device, JSONModel/*, ...*/) {
     "use strict";

     return UIComponent.extend("demo", {
       metadata: { manifest: "json" },
       init: function() {
         UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
         this._setDeviceModel("viewportSize");
         // ...
       },

       _setDeviceModel: function(modelName) {
         const model = new JSONModel(Device.resize, /*observe*/true); // true if the width can change during the runtime
         model.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
         this.setModel(model, modelName);
         return this;
       },

     });
   });
   ```
2. In the view, combine `Device.resize.width` with *expression binding*:

   ```xml
   <IconTabFilter
     text="My Filter"
     icon="{= ${viewportSize>/width} > 500 ? 'sap-icon://something' : undefined }"
   />
   ```

If the viewport width is larger than *x* CSS pixels, the icon is applied. Otherwise, no icons, as demoed in [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBarNoIcons).